# How to get rid of emacs error "void-variable org-format-latex-options"?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm trying to configure the preview of latex-fragments in org-mode using doom-emacs on macOS. I had a working setup before, but for some reason emacs does not recognize this variable anymore.

Latex is installed, org is required in the init.el and the creating/preview of latex fragments is working, but I can't configure e.g. the size of the fragments because of this error.

Is there some specific requirement for the usage of this variable, or what could the origin of the error be?

Comment: This sounds odd to me. `org` is a build-in GNU Emacs package, I see `org-format-latex-option` was added back in 2006; I use it too, and not aware of any specific requirements. What `C-h v org-version` and `C-h v emacs-version` output? Maybe there's a typo in the variable name when you use it? And the standard recommendation, try investigating with the rest of the configs disabled: launch emacs with: `emacs -Q`.

Comment: When/where/how do you get the error? Please describe exactly what you are doing when you get the error.

Comment: @Y.E. org-version is 9.6, emacs version is 27.2

Comment: @NickD I have the following in my config: (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5), the error appears on Emacs start-up (if the line is in config.el) and on "doom sync" (if the line is in init.el)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched around a bit, and found the problem with my setup. The crucial point was that org-format-latex-options is only available *after* org has been loaded. Might be a bit of a nooby error, but I was not aware of this fact, maybe someone else in the future has the same problem...

To fix the error, for me that meant replacing this bit of configuration

```
(plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5)
```

with the following:

```
(after! org (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5))
```

Using this minor modification, Emacs does not report the mentioned error anymore!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue : ) For some reason this doesn't work for me at all. Do you have to place it somewhere special e.g. after all the org related stuff? When I leave it in my init.el file it breaks the init phase of launching emacs. BTW I'm just starting out with emacs so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I am sure you either figured it out, or moved on. For anyone else who finds this though, I fixed it by putting `(plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5)` as the last thing in my `.emacs` file.

Comment: Answer results in `Symbol's function definition is void: after!`